# IPtables logging is not working in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, kernel, iptables, logs

I want to log all the traffic which comes in and out from the port **X**. I have followed below steps.

1. Edited `/etc/syslog.conf` , `/etc/rsyslog.conf` , `/etc/systemd/system/rsyslog.service.d/rsyslog.conf` file to change `kern.warning     /var/log/iptables.log`
2. `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
3. `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport **X** -j LOG --log-level 7`
4. `iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport **X** -j LOG --log-level 7`
5. `tail -f /var/log/iptables.log`
6. I have tried to hit the port **x** from another server.

But, I didn't get any logs get generated in `/var/log/iptables.log`.

Comment: CentOS 7 doesn't use iptables, it uses firewalld.

Comment: But firewalld in turn uses iptables. Right?

Comment: Wrong. It's a different tool altogether. But you can use iptables syntax in firewalld if you feel so inclined.

Comment: the commands inserted with -I here are iptables commands anyway, so firewalld is out of topic. If you really want to not have discussions about firewalld, just stop the firewalld service during your tests and tell the firewalld service is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

After replicating this setup real quick, I think your issue comes from a minor misconception.

Your command `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport **X** -j LOG --log-level 7` does not set the log-level to `WARNING`, but to log-level `DEBUG`.  To set to warning level, you would use `--log-level 4`.

This then leads to using the incorrect log level in your syslog configuration.  When using `--log-level 7` in the `iptables` command, you would want to use `kern.debug` in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`.  You would use `kern.warning` in `rsyslog` when using `--log-level 4` in `iptables`.

Make sure you restart the `rsyslog` service (`systemctl restart rsyslog`) after changing `/etc/rsyslog.conf`.  Also of note, the `/var/log/iptables.log` file would not be created until there was incoming traffic on the desired port to be logged.

Comment: Changed all conf file to kern.warning and used --log-level 4 in iptables. Then restarted the rsyslog service. Tried connecting the port X. Still no logging is happening.

Comment: Make sure you removed any other `LOG` rules from iptables that may conflict.  Also check that traffic is able to reach your `LOG` rule, the output of `iptables --list --verbose` can help there by showing how many packets/bytes passed through each rule.  If your desired `LOG` rule has 0 `pkts` (i.e. packets, first column) then a higher precedence rule is catching the traffic before your `LOG` rule can be applied.

Comment: All the iptable rules are flushed using (iptables -F). And then only followed the above mentioned steps. So, only the above rules are there in the iptables.